# In depth logo pack, dire need of advice

Tags: print-design, logo, color-profile, style-guide

To start off any help is greatly appreciated I posted in the Adobe forms as well with almost no response. 
So I am putting together my first logo pack and like the title states, I'm confused on a few points.

I know we would need multiple options for screen use, color, greyscale, white, black and For print in large scale and small scale, all with those color options again.

I see people list the basics saying you need a CMYK and RGB (in multiple sizes), Spot color (coated and uncoated) white back and greyscale.

So what I do know I need is:

• Color RGB (.ai, .pdf,. png. jpg)(small and lage sizes)

• Color CMYK (.ai, .pdf)(small and lage sizes)

• Spot color (Pantone coated & uncoated)(small and large sizes)

This is where I need more details. We have logos in all black, all white, and greyscale. We use these in both print and web.

•What color profile do these (White, Black, Greyscale logos)  fall under? Does it Matter? Do I need a separate one for print and web?

•With PANTONE - we use these so rarely and so far only in color, is it worth making white, black, and gray scale Pantone variants or just make them when or if it ever comes to it?

•I understand large and small sizes for print, but when referring to web (RGB) what would a large and small size be considered?

•Is it really only necessary to render out jpgs & pngs for RGB since CMYK being used with print should use vector or pdf files?

As you can see I am quite lost with this and any help would be more than appreciated!

Comment: So what exactly do you want to know? I'm confused to what's your actual question, please only add as much details as needed to give context to your question.

Comment: I apologize, I lost track of what I was trying to get across, I reworded my original questions.

Comment: I don't look for color in logo packs, I like to color them myself. They usually come in black. With vector size is not as much of a concern as the icons can be scaled in programs or in css, but they are often offered at 16px, 32px and 64px. So .PNGs in RGB are best for my needs.

Answer (score 1):

> What color profile do these (White, Black, Greyscale logos) fall
>   under? Does it Matter? Do I need a separate one for print and web?

If the white, black greyscale logos are for web make them RGB, if they're for print make them CMYK. This isn't a big deal for white but black will matter for printing CMYK since 0,0,0,100k is dark grey.

> With PANTONE - we use these so rarely and so far only in color, is it
>   worth making white, black, and gray scale Pantone variants or just
>   make them when or if it ever comes to it?

You don't need a pantone for white, and our company has a pantone grey but we don't always call for it when printing.

> I understand large and small sizes for print, but when referring to web (RGB) what would a large and small size be considered?

I haven't seen any standard, I have usually done 250px, 500px and 1500px. I would also recommend exporting as SVG and then you can scale to any size.

> Is it really only necessary to render out jpgs & pngs for RGB since
>   CMYK being used with print should use vector or pdf files?

Yes, if you have a vector logo you should also export as svg for web.

Comment: This is perfect, thank you so much for your input!